# What is the difference between Initial Review and Regular Review in Review Assistant?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, devart

I'm using Review Assistant in Visual Studio 2017.  When creating a review there are two options, Regular Review and Initial Review.  I was wondering what the difference is between them?  All I could find was Initial Review was to review the project in current state, so the most recent revision of the file(s) selected are added to the review.  Is that it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

We are very sorry for delay in replying. Hope this information will still be helpful.

The initial review mode allows reviewing code of a project in its current state, whereas the regular review provides only the inspection of the incremental changes to the code. This feature is particularly useful to those who are starting to review the code in a project.

1. Files, not revisions, are added to a review. The latest revision of
   the file is retrieved from the repository.
2. Any number of files can be added in a review from the repository.
3. Based on the comments, the latest revisions of files can be added to
   a review and several iterations can be implemented.

More information about the difference can be found at 
[docs.devart.com/review-assistant/creating-review/creating-regular-review.html](http://docs.devart.com/review-assistant/creating-review/creating-regular-review.html) and
[docs.devart.com/review-assistant/creating-review/creating-initial-review-for-project.html](http://docs.devart.com/review-assistant/creating-review/creating-initial-review-for-project.html)

In case of any further questions please feel free to contact our support team any time.

Best regards.